# facing problem while try to read ,tab file in R

Tags: r

I am using illumina sequencing based data. I have problems while trying to read .tab file in R.
I tried to run working directory and get this error,

```
getwd()

setwd("D:/plan A/find new data set/selecting dataset procedure/ENRICHMENT/FILES/WILD TYPE/DORSAL DG")
```

the result is

> Error in setwd("D:/plan A/find new data set/selecting dataset procedure/ENRICHMENT/\n \n FILES/WILD TYPE/DORSAL DG") :
> cannot change working directory

Answer (score 1):

You could use `choose.dir()` to select the working directory but this is OS-Specific...

```
choose.dir(getwd(), "Search for the specific folder")
```

Another OS-Independent way is to use:

```
library(tcltk)
dir <- tclvalue(tkchooseDirectory())
setwd(dir)
```

ALSO in your error "/ENRICHMENT/\n \n FILES/" you get \n's which causes the problem. Just set it to be in one line while copying and issue should also be solved!

Comment: Yep. Almost every time I have a directory problem, its because of the direction of my lines being \ instead of /